# String to Bool value f#

Tags: f#

I'm trying to create a function that converts a string to a bool.
This is what I have for now

```
let iscomb=
    Table.parseTable table
    |>> fun row -> row.["IsComb"] |> Models.Bool //returns true or false from a table cell


let Bool (s:string) =
        match (s) with
        | "true" -> true
        | "false" -> false
        | _-> sprintf "Error: returns %s" s
```

This return *the type bool does not match the type string*

So what I have understod is that we cannot mix different types in a match.
Any suggestion on what I could do?

Thanks in advace.

Comment: You could throw an exception, or use a ``Result`` type.

Comment: The problem is you are trying to RETURN both bool and string. This is for any expression, not just match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for `fun`, I thought I would demonstrate using [Active Patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/active-patterns) for this. Only really worthwhile if you are checking this often and wanting to do different things based on that and you want to expand what is accepted beyond "true" / "false". It also can remove typo errors like *"fasle"*.

First, we create 2 partial Active Patterns that just cleanup checking for `Int32` and `bool` from `string`.

> Note: You could just use the `Bool` AP below and stop there.

```
// Partial active pattern that matches on Int32
let (|Int|_|) (value:string) =
    match (System.Int32.TryParse(value)) with
    | (true, i) -> Some i
    | (false,_) -> None 

// Partial active pattern that matches on Bool
let (|Bool|_|) (value:string) =
    match (System.Boolean.TryParse(value)) with
    | (true,b) -> Some b
    | _ -> None
```

Next, we use those 2 partial Active Patterns to cleanly test our string in an active pattern with 2 choices.

```
// Active pattern that buckets a string into True or False (or throws)
let(|True|False|) (value:string) =
    match value with
    | null -> False
    | Int i when i > 0 -> True
    | Int i when i <= 0 -> False 
    | Bool true -> True
    | Bool false -> False
    | _ -> failwithf "Cannot convert %s to bool." value
```

So how would we use this? Here is a `test` function where we use the Active Pattern to test a few results.

```
// quick little function to test a string
let test s =
    match s with
    | True -> printfn "The value %s is true" s
    | False -> printfn "The value %s is false" s
```

Resulting in the following:

```
// testing
test "true"     // The value true is true
test "TRUE"     // The value TRUE is true
test "false"    // The value false is false
test "False"    // The value False is false
test "-1"       // The value -1 is false
test "42"       // The value 42 is true
test null       // The value  is false
test "abc"      // System.Exception: Cannot convert abc to bool.
```

For more info:

- [FSharp for fun and Profit](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/convenience-active-patterns/)
- [F# Online meetup talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q5KO-UDx5eA)

Answer (score 1):

You could replace sprintf for failwith, throwing an exception:

```
let Bool s =
    match s with
    | "true" -> true
    | "false" -> false
    | _-> failwith("Error: returns " + s)
```